# Como passar texto da textbox para report, com VS 2015, em C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer, visual-studio-2015

Estou a criar uma app para o local onde trabalho, que deverá imprimir uns rótulos baseados em informação que introduzo num formulário criado por mim.

Para isso, estou a criar uma versão mais reduzida, para testar se tudo o que pretendo funciona. Estou a usar o Visual Studio 2015 Community com arquivos no formato RDLC.

Tenho um form com uma `textbox` de nome "tb_info", e um *report* com um parâmetro de nome "param_info". O objectivo é, ao pressionar o botão do form, ele passa a informação da `textbox` para o parâmetro do *report*, dando a ordem para imprimir o report de seguida.

Alguma ideia para realizar isto?

Comment: Vai usar Report Viewer? Sua aplicação é WPF ou MVC?

Comment: Facilita se usar o ReportViewer!?

Comment: Preciso saber mais coisas. Se for uma aplicação Web, por exemplo, não acho. Se for WPF pode até compensar, dependendo.

Comment: Não é web, estou a criar como uma aplicação executável normal (será MVC creio eu).

Comment: [Algo assim](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: É algo bastante mais simples, são rótulos com 11cm x 20cm, e contém apenas entre 3 a 4 campos de texto, tudo o resto é meramente decorativo (logo da empresa e do cliente, mais o transportador). Não sei se ajuda mas a versão .NET usada na empresa é a 4.5

Comment: O link fornecido à duas linhas atrás é apenas para criar os reports certo?! Porque o VS2015 deixa criar um report em rdlc, que eu usei para criar o layout do rótulo!!

Comment: Bom, você quer usar Report Viewer e RDLC, então. Sem problemas. Não tenho todo o conhecimento específico pra te dar uma resposta. Vou editar novamente sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Segue um template de uma action que retornaria o relatório no formato PDF, este conceito aborda o carregamento do "RDLC", o bind com o "DataSource" e atribuição de variáveis, espero que seja útil:

```
public FileResult GetRelatorio()
{
    ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();
    report.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Relatório";

    //Carregue o rdlc do seu relatório
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("meu_relatorio.rdlc", FileMode.Open))
       report.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);

    //Adicione o seu datasource
    report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource
    {
        Name = "Nome no data source",
        Value = "Seu data source"
    });

    //Dê valor aos parâmetros do seu relatório
    ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[]{
        new ReportParameter("Texto1", txt1.Text),
        new ReportParameter("Texto2", txt2.Text)
    };
    report.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

    //Gere o seu relatório em PDF
    byte[] Arquivo = report.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Arquivo);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```